# Issue upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.1 using UNIX Sockets

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.1

When upgrading an application to ASP.NET Core 2.1, UNIX sockets no longer work and the application throws an unhandled exception on startup:

> System.ArgumentException: Only ListenType.IPEndPoint is supported.

How do I listen on UNIX sockets using ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 2.1, the Kestrel server switched to the "Sockets" transport implementation, which only supports IP sockets.

In order to use UNIX sockets, the "LibUV" transport implementation needs to be used instead.

To do this, change the startup code to select the LibUV transport:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseLibuv()
        .UseUrls("http://unix:/var/run/myapi.sock")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And then change the csproj file to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` metapackage instead of the `.App` metapackage:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Change to ".All" if this was ".App" -->
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" />
</ItemGroup>
```